# How can I specify hosts when importing a playbook

Tags: ansible

ansible version: 2.9

Hi.

How can I specify the hosts when I import a playbook with `import_playbook`?

My code (`/project/first_pb.yml`)

```yaml
- import_playbook: /test/pb0.yml
  hosts: atlanta
```

Comment: The code must be inline. There are no [keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) for *import_playbook*. [*import_playbook*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html#ansible-builtin-import-playbook-import-a-playbook) is not a task.

Comment: Vladimir, If import_playbook is not a task what is? a Play? If he is a Play why "hosts" keyword don't run.

Comment: *import_playbook* does not belong to any category of [*play, role, block, task*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords). The reasoning is simple. What's inside of *import_playbook*? The answer is a play. In Ansible hierarchy, is there any structure above a play? The answer is no. As a result, there can't be any Ansible directive modifying *include_playbook*. What is it then? In fact, it's only simple import that should help you to structure a large playbook including many plays.

Comment: You know a method to pass specific family hosts to imported playbook?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can filter play plabooks with "when: " condition, for example:

```
- import_playbook: /test/pb0.yml
  when: hostname != host1a*

- import_playbook: /test/pb0.yml
  when: '"north" not in hostname'

- import_playbook: /test/pb0.yml
  when: '"west" in hostname'
```

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"A method to pass specific family hosts to the imported playbook?"***

A: There is no difference between a playbook imported or not. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb-A.yml
- hosts: "{{ my_hosts|default('localhost') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname

shell> ansible-playbook pb-A.yml -e my_hosts=host1
...
  inventory_hostname: host1
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb-B.yml
- import_playbook: pb-A.yml

shell> ansible-playbook pb-B.yml -e my_hosts=host1
...
  inventory_hostname: host1
```

There are many options on how to pass specific hosts and groups to a playbook. For example, see:

- [Patterns: targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-targeting-hosts-and-groups)
- [add_host module – Add a host and group to the ansible-playbook in-memory inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html#ansible-builtin-add-host-module-add-a-host-and-alternatively-a-group-to-the-ansible-playbook-in-memory-inventory)
- Inventory plugins (e.g. *constructed*)